# how to get and set hyperparameter from a mlr Wrapper

Tags: mlr

I run the following to train a wrapped model from some task. I want to get the hyper-parameters from the wrapper.  I tried the following

```
library(mlr)
lrn = makeLearner("classif.ksvm")
lrn = makeRemoveConstantFeaturesWrapper(lrn)
df = getTaskData(sonar.task)
df$constant = 1
task = makeClassifTask(data = df, target = "Class")
model = train(learner = lrn, task = sonar.task)
model
getHyperPars(model)
```

I got the following message.

```
Error in UseMethod("getHyperPars") : 
  no applicable method for 'getHyperPars' applied to an object of class "c('PreprocModel', 'BaseWrapperModel', 'WrappedModel')"
```

How can I get and set hyper-parameters for a wrapped model? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply it on the learner:

```
getHyperPars(lrn)
```

This only gives hyperparameters that are set explicitly.

Comment: I need to get HyperPars from Model, not Learner

Comment: but getHyperPars(model$learner) only get you the hyper-pars of the base learner, not the removeConstantFeatures

Comment: Can it be that you are not talking about the hyper-parameters but the model-parameters? That would be the features that are removed in this case? The only hyper par that `makeRemoveConstantFeaturesWrapper` is `perc` and that you have to define by yourself.